# How to use https module with uri?

Tags: node.js, https, request-promise

I am trying to use native https module in nodejs.

The code sample below works fine with request-promise-native library

```
var apiver = '2017-09-01';
var resource = 'https://management.azure.com/';
const rp = require('request-promise-native');
var options = {
    uri: `${process.env["MSI_ENDPOINT"]}/?resource=${resource}&api-version=${apiver}`,
    headers: {
        'Secret': process.env["MSI_SECRET"]
    }
};
return rp(options);
```

Here the uri = "http://127.0.0.1:41437/MSI/token//?resource=https://management.azure.com/&api-version=2017-09-01"

But if I try to do the same thing using https module it throws error

```
return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    var apiver = '2017-09-01';
    var resource = 'https://management.azure.com/';
    var options = {
        "method": "GET",
        "hostname": "localhost",
        "port": 41437,
        "protocol": "https:",
        "path": `/MSI/token/?resource=${resource}&api-version=${apiver}`,
        headers: {
            'Secret': process.env["MSI_SECRET"]
        }
    };
    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
        var body = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            if (res.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(body);
            } else {
                reject({'error':null,'res':res});
            }
        });
    });
    req.on('error', function (e) {
        reject({'error':e,'res':null});
    });
    req.end();
});
```

Following error is thrown

```
{ 
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 41437,
    protocol: 'https:',
    path: '/MSI/token/?resource=https://management.azure.com/&api-version=2017-09-01',
    headers: { Secret: '41A1BDD07D4B42159F71353FCCE2F0EB' } }
    2018-10-05T11:36:12.395 [Info] { error: {    
        Error: connect EACCES 127.0.0.1:41437
          at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
          at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
          at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
        code: 'EACCES',
        errno: 'EACCES',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 41437 
    },
    res: null 
}
```

Is it not possible to do this request with native https module?

Comment: The port could be In use. Have you set another daemon and forgotten about it? It could also be that the current user Jas insufficient privileges

Comment: @PatrickSturm nops because when I run the first code on same machine it runs

Comment: Also note that I can't check the link because it points to my own computer (localhost), perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: @PatrickSturm I think link is not the issue because as I mentioned the same url works with request-promise-native module.